# How to set different backgrounds for each page in LaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am trying to set different backgrounds in each page of my LaTeX document. I have tried with tikz, background and many other packages I found, but I couldn't.

I.E.

First page: `\maketitle` with one background

Second page: `\tableofcontents` with a different background

Third pages and following: Content with another background

[Edit 1]

There is something I didn't explain well. Your code helped me a lot, but I tried to modify it and had some problems.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor} \definecolor{letras_portada}{RGB}{229,238,245}




\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{First_page.png}}
\begin{textblock*}{15cm}(6.35cm,23cm) 
    \huge{\textcolor{letras_portada}{\textbf{Report}}}
\end{textblock*}

\cleardoublepage

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Index.png}}
\paragraph{}
\clearpage

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Content.png}}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{section 1}
text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example
\subsection{2}
text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1
\subsubsection{3}
text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1



\end{document}
```

What I pretend as is to have a first page with my title (instead of maketitle I a text), a second page with an specific background but without text and in the third page I'd like to have the table of contents. But second page disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is the `eso-pic` package. With `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{}` you can change the background of the current page, with `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{}` of the current and all following pages.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\author{names}
\title{title}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}}
\maketitle

\cleardoublepage
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-grid-100x100bp}}

\chapter{title}
text

\end{document}
```

---

To add background only pages in a one sides documentclass, you could use this quick hack:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor} \definecolor{letras_portada}{RGB}{229,238,245}




\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}
\begin{textblock*}{15cm}(6.35cm,23cm) 
    \huge{\textcolor{letras_portada}{\textbf{Report}}}
\end{textblock*}
\mbox{}

\newpage

\mbox{}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}}


\newpage

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-c}}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{section 1}
text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example
\subsection{2}
text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1
\subsubsection{3}
text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1text example 1

\newpage
\ClearShipoutPictureBG
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}}
\mbox{}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I added an Edit to the question.

Comment: @Kanayel I added a quick hack, please see my updated answer.

Comment: And how would you add another empty page with a different background at the end? @samcarter

Comment: @Kanayel `\newpage

\mbox{}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}}`

Comment: Could you check my edit 3? I couldn't add this last page.@samcarter

Comment: @Kanayel I don't see any edit 3, but I modified my answer to include a last page